# Create a dynamic dropdown in react

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a function in React that returns a dropdown by looping through an array. However, I get an error `Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null`. Here is my code:

```
function list(props){

  let arr = props.school;
  let dropdown = document.querySelector("#dropdown");
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  dropdown.innerHTML += `<option>${arr[i].name}</option>`;
  }

  function handle(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

  }

  return (

      <div className="overall">
        <select id="dropdown" className="btn btn-success" onClick={handle}></select>
      </div>
  );
}
```

I'm not sure why but if I turn my code into this (move it into the onclick function):

```
function list(props){

  function handle(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let arr = props.school;
    let dropdown = document.querySelector("#dropdown");
    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    dropdown.innerHTML += `<option>${arr[i].name}</option>`;
  }

  }

  return (

      <div className="overall">
        <select id="dropdown" className="btn btn-success" onClick={handle}></select>
      </div>
  );
}
```

The dropdown renders but I have to click on it to work which is not ideal. Could anyone help with this null issue?

Comment: it seems your query selector `document.querySelector("#dropdown")` returns null. Just add a `console.log(dropdown)` before the loop to see what's in it.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the best way to render React components. A better way would be:

```
return (
   <div className="overall">
     <select id="dropdown" className="btn btn-success" onClick={handle}>
      {
        arr.map(item => {
          return <option key={item.name} value={item.name}>{item.name}</option>
        });
      }
    </select>
   </div>
);
```

You don't need the querySelector and the other for loop. That is a jQuery way of doing things.